# On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Usando o hibernate com a classe:

Texto.java

```
package br.com.meusite.model.documento;

@Entity
public class Texto extends ABeanDao<Texto> {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     private static final int cMaxTamanhoIndice = 2712;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long idTexto;

     @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "Text")
     private String textoBruto;

     @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "Text")
     private String idAlternativo;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "idTextoAnteriorParteDoTexto", nullable = true)
     @ForeignKey(name = "fk_texto_textoAnteriorParteDoTexto")
     private Texto textoAnteriorParteDoTexto;

     public Texto(){}

     //getters and setters

}
```

Quando faz uma consulta com like no banco atraves do hibernate me retorno no final da consulta a seguinte mensagem:

```
DEBUG ResultSetProcessorImpl:127 - Starting ResultSet row #0
DEBUG EntityReferenceInitializerImpl:142 - On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [br.com.meusite.model.documento.Texto#265752]
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:286 - Done materializing entity [br.com.meusite.model.documento.Texto#265752]
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [br.com.meusite.model.documento.Texto#265751]
```

Segue a consulta também.

```
select * 
 from
    Texto texto0_ 
left outer join
    Texto texto18_ 
        on texto0_.idTextoAnteriorParteDoTexto=texto18_.idTexto 
where
    texto0_.idTexto=?
```

Porém teria que gerar uma consulta `LIKE`(texto0_.idAlternativo like ?) e nao texto0_.idTexto=?

Qual a possível solução para o problema?

Comment: Poste também a sua consulta. Só para esta consulta que dá o erro? Alguma outra query (crud) acontece o problema?

Comment: Nenhuma CRUD acontece o erro somente essa

Comment: Isso é no mínimo incomum ou suspeito: `Texto extends ABeanDao<Texto>`. O que há nessa interface?

Comment: a interface eh apenas um CRUD padrao, sao onde tem os metodo de create, delete, insert e select nada demais, em todas as outras rodam normal